# DropDownListFor Not Selecting Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the DropDownListFor helper method inside of an edit page and I'm not having any luck getting it to select the value that I specify. I noticed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916462/dropdownlistfor-in-editortemplate-not-selecting-value) on Stackoverflow. The suggested workaround was to, "populate your SelectList in the view code". The problem is that I've already tried this and it's still not working.

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.States, new SelectList(Model.States.OrderBy(s => s.StateAbbr), "StateAbbr", "StateName", Model.AddressStateAbbr), "-- Select State --")%>
```

I have set a breakpoint and have verified the existence (and validity) of model.AddressStateAbbr. I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

After researching for an hour, I found the problem that is causing the selected to not get set to `DropDownListFor`.  The reason is you are using ViewBag's name the same as the model's property.

Example

```
public  class employee_insignia
{ 
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string name{get;set;}
   public int insignia{get;set;}//This property will store insignia id
}

// If your ViewBag's name same as your property name 
  ViewBag.Insignia = new SelectList(db.MtInsignia.AsEnumerable(), "id", "description", 1);
```

View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.insignia, (SelectList)ViewBag.Insignia, "Please select value")
```

The selected option will not set to dropdownlist, BUT When you change ViewBag's name to different name the selected option will show correct.

Example

```
ViewBag.InsigniaList = new SelectList(db.MtInsignia.AsEnumerable(), "id", "description", 1);
```

View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.insignia, (SelectList)ViewBag.InsigniaList , "Please select value")
```

Comment: This is actually a correct answer!!! To everyone googling, make sure you don't name the ViewBag property the same as the model property! I did not expect this to matter at all, but it actually fixed it. I'm shocked.

Comment: I have the same problem, even though the ViewBag property has a different name to the model property: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.Salutation, Resources.Labels.Unknown )`

Comment: This problem even happens for a different multi select drop down list which uses a SelectList from the ViewBag as a data source!! So if you are having problems with any select lists/multiselect lists then definitely check that this isn't your problem!
eg. model.DepartmentsSelectList = new MultiSelectList((SelectList)ViewBag.Departments, "Value", "Text", selectedDepartments);  where model.Departments exists.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason why they can't be the same? This answer saved my laptop from being smashed :)

Comment: For the record, if you forget to use a property signature (without get;set; , making it a member but public ) then the dropdown item won't be selected either. Just lost 4 hours on this

Comment: This is true for `ViewData` also. Do not name the index same.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm having this issue also and we're not using ViewBag. Also the question wasn't using ViewBag

Comment: I wrapped my offending view model property 'Title' in another property called 'TitleDropDownListForBug'. #selfdocumentingcode

Comment: I consider this an ASP.NET MVC bug!

Comment: I am not sure why this is the problem, I wish that I did. Naming them differently fixed some of my issues but I also found out that trailing spaces can cause this issue as well. Edit:Spelling

Comment: I was having the same problem, In my case none of model properties' name was matching but name I was using was matching a model that I was not using for this controller/razor page, so strongly recommended use different name for ViewBag.ListObject in any case. Question was asked long ago but still this bug is there, even there are no warnings.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the dropdown name can be the same as the property name, but you have to leave the second parameter = null.
E.g.:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Insignia, null, "Please select value")

Answer (score 36):

If you're doing it properly and using a model--unlike all these ViewBag weirdos--and still seeing the issue, it's because `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyValue, @Model.MyOptions)` can't match `MyValue` with the choices it has in `MyOptions`. The two potential reasons for that are:

1. `MyValue` is null. You haven't set it in your ViewModel. Making one of `MyOptions` have a `Selected=true` won't solve this.
2. More subtly, the **type** of `MyValue` is different than the types in `MyOptions`. So like, if `MyValue` is `(int) 1`, but your `MyOptions` are a list of padded strings `{"01", "02", "03", ...}`, it's obviously not going to select anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I also don't understand why everyone is using ViewBag instead of creating a proper view model. This answer was staring me in the face and I appreciate you connecting the dots.

Comment: #2 here is my issue. I have a model property that is a delegate type with a custom model binder to take in the name of the Method and actually bind that method from a list of predefined method calls that match the delegate signature. Has anyone found a was to work around #2 and make it select correctly without some hacky clients side script?

Comment: Also, to anyone who has a SelectList with a different value attribute than the display text between the option tags for example: `<option value="2">some text</option>`. It looks to be actually trying to match the view model property with the display text and not the value attribute to choose the selected option.  This had me going for a while.

Comment: Because it seems a bit overboard to have to change a model just to contain a simple list of items that you want to contain in a dropdown

Comment: ViewBag is dynamic, so you move any potential type-safety issues from the compile time--where they're easy to see--out into the runtime, where they're much harder to nab (as is the case in your last question to s.o.)

Answer (score 32):

Try:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.AddressStateAbbr,
    new SelectList(
        Model.States.OrderBy(s => s.StateAbbr),
        "StateAbbr",
        "StateName",
        Model.AddressStateAbbr), "-- Select State --")%>
```

or in Razor syntax:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.AddressStateAbbr,
    new SelectList(
        Model.States.OrderBy(s => s.StateAbbr),
        "StateAbbr",
        "StateName",
        Model.AddressStateAbbr), "-- Select State --")
```

The expression based helpers don't seem to respect the Selected property of the SelectListItems in your SelectList.

Answer (score 18):

While not addressing this question - it may help future googlers if they followed my thought path:

I wanted a multiple select and this attribute hack on ***DropDownListFor*** wasn't auto selecting

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TrainingLevelSelected, Model.TrainingLevelSelectListItems, new {multiple= "multiple" })
```

instead I should have been using ***ListBoxFor*** which made everything work

```
Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.TrainingLevelSelected, Model.TrainingLevelSelectListItems)
```

Comment: I followed your thought path.  World: if you're using DropDownListFor and multiple, you meant to use ListBoxFor.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I have been having the same issue in 2020.

It turns out the issue was with the model property being called "Title", I renamed it to "GivenTitle" and it now works as expected.

From

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

to

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GivenTitle, Model.GivenTitles, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Tried all solutions above and didn't work and this solved it! Seems like "Title" is some special word!

Comment: If anyone figures out why title is a special word please let me know. I've been banging my head all day with this issue

Answer (score 1):

I also having similar issue and I solve it by as follows,
set the

model.States property on your controller to what you need to be selected

model.States="California"

and then you will get "California" as default value.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to check if it's not all your own code, is to make sure there's not a javascript function changing the value on page load. After hours of banging my head against a wall reading through all these solutions, I discovered this is what was happening with me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue recently. It drove me mad for about an hour. 
In my case, I **wasn't** using a `ViewBag` variable with the same name as the model property.

After tracing source control changes, the issue turned out to be that my **action** had an **argument with the same name** as the model property:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string someName)
{
    var model = new SomeModel();
    model.SomeNames = GetSomeList();
    //Notice how the model property name matches the action name
    model.someName = someName; 
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.someName, Model.SomeNames)
```

I simply changed the action's argument to some other name and it started working again:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string someOtherName)
{
    //....
}
```

I suppose one could also change the model's property name but in my case, the argument name is meaningless so...

Hopefully this answer saves someone else the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The issue at least for me was tied to the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Basically what happened was that the view and the model did not have the same reference for the same property.

If you do this

```
IEnumerable<CoolName> CoolNames {get;set;} = GetData().Select(x => new CoolName{...});}
```

Then bind this using the

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.CoolNames)
```

The View loses track of the CoolNames property,
a simple fix is just to add `.ToList()` After dooing a projection  (`.Select()`) ;).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the example below The variable  ViewData["DATA_ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"] has a SelectListItem list with a default selected value but such attribute is not reflected visually.

```
// data 
        var p_estadoAcreditacion = "NO";
        var estadoAcreditacion = new List<SelectListItem>();
        estadoAcreditacion.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "(SELECCIONE)"    , Value = " "    });
        estadoAcreditacion.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SI"              , Value = "SI"   });
        estadoAcreditacion.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "NO"              , Value = "NO"   });

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_estadoAcreditacion))
        {
            estadoAcreditacion.First(x => x.Value == p_estadoAcreditacion.Trim()).Selected = true;
        }
         ViewData["DATA_ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"] = estadoAcreditacion;
```

I solved it by making the first argument of DropdownList, different to the id attribute.

```
// error:
@Html.DropDownList("SELECT__ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"
, ViewData["DATA_ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"] as List<SelectListItem>
, new
{
id         = "SELECT__ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"
...
// solved :
@Html.DropDownList("DROPDOWNLIST_ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"
, ViewData["DATA_ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"] as List<SelectListItem>
, new
{
id         = "SELECT__ACREDITO_MODELO_INTEGRADO"
```

...

Answer (score -1):

this problem is common. change viewbag property name to other then model variable name used on page.