# Selected value not set on DropDownListFor() in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, drop-down-menu

It seems like this question has been asked too many times. But this is driving me nuts.

This is my (simplified) model.

```
public class UserEditModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _titleList;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TitleList
    {
        get { return _titleList.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
                            Selected = (x.Value == Title), 
                            Text = x.Text,
                            Value = x.Value
                        });
        }
        set { _titleList = value; }
    }
}
```

The `Text` and `Value` properties of each `SelectListItem` in the `TitleList` member are identical. For example:

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr"  }
```

When the following code is posted, the correct `Title` value is bound to the model, but whenever the model is pushed to the view in response to a POST or a GET, the selected value is not set on the dropdownlist, even though all the intellisense shows that the correct values are present.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, Model.TitleList)
```

I have ensured that the code is correct based on several articles and several SO answers, so I am stumped.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

For completeness, this is the action and supporting method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var user = _userService.Get(id);

    var model = new UserEditModel()
    {
        ...
        Title = user.Title,
        TitleList = ListTitles()
    };

    return View(model);
}

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListTitles()
{
    var items = new[] {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr" },
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mrs", Value = "Mrs"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Ms", Value = "Ms"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Professor", Value = "Professor"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Dr", Value = "Dr" }
        };

    return items;
}
```

As you see there is nothing fancy, just a straightforward implementation.

Comment: Try adding `ModelState.Clear()` just before you return your view.

Comment: @mattytommo Why should I need to do this? Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: See my answer, that's why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems there is actually nothing wrong with the code, just the name of the `Title` property in the model.

It looks like `Title` is a reserved word and replacing it with `TitleX` or more appropriately `Salutation` makes everything work fine.

Comment: Thanks fella.  I've had this exact same problem - even used the same property names as you.  Just spent a couple of hours pulling my hair out over this.  As we say down our way: "what a crock of shit..."

Comment: Same problem here, must catch a lot of people out. However I've now got another drop down not selecting the right value. I can see the value set to the Model in the template but it's not getting selected. Every other drop down works fine and I can't see any difference in the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278056/dropdownlistfor-not-selecting-value

Fixed! I was assigning a ViewBag property with the same name as the model property, which is a big no-no apparently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `ModelState.Clear()` because by default when returning a view from a post action, it thinks it has failed validation, so uses the values in `ModelState` and **not** the values in the Model. Many people think this is actually a **bug** in MVC, but it's by design:

> ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to a `HttpPost`, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely to be redisplaying a form that has failed validation. Therefore, the Html Helpers actually check in `ModelState` for the value to display in a field before they look in the Model. This enables them to redisplay erroneous data that was entered by the user, and a matching error message if needed.

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx)

Comment: The problem isn't with the POST/ModelState. The selected value isn't set ever, on a POST or GET. My mention of the POST was to show the model was set up correctly and so was unlikely to be a problem with the model.

Comment: @Digbyswift If you can see it in the action it's going to right before it's hitting the view, it is **almost certainly** `ModelState`. Did you try adding the `.Clear`?

Comment: @Digbyswift Could you also post your action? Just to make sure nothings up with that.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You'll see it's pretty basic which is why it is bugging me so much.

Comment: Hmm that's weird, all looks fine. You say when debugging it you can verify the value in `model.Title` before it hits the view yeah?

Comment: Yes, I can manually create a dropdownlist with a loop matching the correct option against the `Model.Title` property.

Comment: Hmmm, can you post the rest of your view? I think I may know the issue.

Comment: No need. I figured out the answer. Looks like `Title` was a reserved word. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This was driving me crazy.  I added ModelState.Clear() and that fixed it.  I would have never thought of that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you retrieve the selectlist item appropriately in the controller?
For me it is working fine.
I would use a get method instead of a property ( `GetTitleList(string value)` ), to avoid mistakes in getting the selectionlist farther along in your code.

Comment: Regardless of the implementation, if the code works for you it should work for me shouldn't it? And yes, as I say in the OP the values are all correct. It's a mystery!