# Issue with DownDownList display type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an intranet, specifically on a Weekly Monitoring tool that lets me see the Activity of my employees week by week. I'm working on the *week by week* filter. So far I have figured out how to create a `List` containing every week of 2015 in the following format :

```
From dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy
```

Like such :

```
public ActionResult WeeklyMonitoring()
{  
    ProjectResourceManagerService pr = new ProjectResourceManagerService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));

    List<string> wl = pr.FetchWeeks(DateTime.Now.Year); // Creates the list
    ViewBag.Weeks = wl;
    wl.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m });           
    return View();
}
```

But here's the issue, when I select a week in my `DropDownList` (Where I had to convert it to the right type) :

```
  <td><%: Html.DropDownList("Weeks", ((List<string>)ViewBag.Weeks).Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();"}) %></td>
```

And it sends a form to :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WeeklyMonitoring(FormCollection form)
{
    string week = form["Weeks"];            

    ViewBag.Weeks = week;
    return View();
}
```

I get the obvious following error :

> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

How may I avoid this error, and keep the selected week in my `DropDownList` after the form is sent?

EDIT :

So far I have found this solution, probably isn't practical for a filter but here I go :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WeeklyMonitoring(FormCollection form)
{
    string week = form["Weeks"];           

    ProjectResourceManagerService pr = new ProjectResourceManagerService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));

    List<string> wl = pr.FetchWeeks(DateTime.Now.Year);
    wl.Remove(week);
    wl.Insert(0, week);
    wl.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m });
    ViewBag.Weeks = wl;
    return View();
}
```

I remove the item from the list and put it on top, so it gets displayed by the DDList.

EDIT2 :

Adding `FetchWeeks` :

```
  public List<string> FetchWeeks(int year)
    {
        List<string> weeks = new List<string>();
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1 - (int)startDate.DayOfWeek);
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(6);
        while (startDate.Year < 1 + year)
        {
            weeks.Add(string.Format("From {0:dd/MM/yyyy} to {1:dd/MM/yyyy}", startDate, endDate));
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
            endDate = endDate.AddDays(7);
        }
        return weeks;
    }
```

EDIT3 : Thanks to kikyalex we have found a solution :

When the ViewBag property has the same name as the DDList that creates a problem that stops it from changing its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string week = form["Weeks"];            

 ViewBag.Weeks = week;
```

You get the current week from your dropdown and pass it into view again. Then you cast it as `List<string>`. It's normal to get an error.

You should use the Selected property from `SelectListItem`

```
public ActionResult WeeklyMonitoring()
{  
    ProjectResourceManagerService pr = new ProjectResourceManagerService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));

    List<string> wl = pr.FetchWeeks(DateTime.Now.Year); // Creates the list
    ViewBag.Weeks =  wl.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m }).ToList();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult WeeklyMonitoring(FormCollection form)
{
    string week = form["Weeks"];           

    ProjectResourceManagerService pr = new ProjectResourceManagerService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));

    List<string> wl = pr.FetchWeeks(DateTime.Now.Year);
    ViewBag.Weeks =   wl.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m, Value = m, Selected = m == week }).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

In you view change the cast to `List<SelectListItem>` instead of `List<string>`

```
 <td><%: Html.DropDownList("Weeks", ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Weeks), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();"}) %></td>
```

Comment: I still seem to get `Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>` after checking and changing it as you said.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to change the GET method too. Updated my answer

Comment: No more errors ! But it still brings me back to the previous date. (Doesn't change to the selected one). Does ViewBag.Weeks not contain the selected one by now? EDIT : I now Weeks contains the list of weeks, but how come the form doesn't let the selected week in the DDList box?

Comment: ViewBag.Weeks should contain each week as a `SelectListItem` object, and only one of them should have Selected == true. You should debug your code and see if `week` variable contains what you selected from dropdown

Comment: It does contain what I selected from the dropdown.

Comment: I have added `FetchWeek`, perhaps the issue comes from here.

Comment: According to the accepted answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566560/html-dropdownlist-selected-value-not-working-using-constructor-with-ienumberabl), there is a problem if the Viewbag property has the same name as the dropdownlist

Comment: How odd, that was the problem ! Thank you so much for your help.