# modelBinding works when using model but not with viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a dropdown show the right value when editing using a viewmodel but it only works when i pass the complete model to the view.

When I do it like this and there is already a contact selected it shows that contact in the edit screen.

**Model**

```
public class ClientModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int ContactID { get; set; }
  //Other atributes
}
```

**View EditContact**

```
@model Project.Models.ClientModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactID , (SelectList)ViewBag.ContactID, "select a contact")
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult EditContact(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var Contact = db.Contacts.ToList();
        ViewBagID.Contact = new SelectList(Contact.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "name", "Contact");
        ClientModel model= db.ClientModel.Find(id);

        return View(model);
    }
```

But when I do it like this and there is already a contact selected the dropdownlist shows select contact.

**Model**

```
public class ClientModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int ContactID { get; set; }
  //Other atributes
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ClientEditContactModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int ContactID { get; set; }
}
```

**View EditContact**

```
@model Project.Models.ClientEditContactModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ContactID, "select a contact")
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult EditContact(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var Contact = db.Contacts.ToList();
        ViewBag.ContactID = new SelectList(Contact.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "name", "Contact");
        ClientModel client= db.ClientModel.Find(id);
        ClientEditContactModel model = new ClientEditContactModel();

        model.ID = client.ID;
        model.ContactID = client.ContactID 

        return View(model);
    }
```

How do i fix this with the viewmodel?

**Edit**
I've made some typo's in my code so I fixed them but because of them i found the answer see below.

Comment: model => model.Contact. Where does your model get this property? Neither ClientModel nor ClientEditContactModel have a property called Contact. Is this a misspell?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be ContactID i fixed it.

Comment: I can not see any reason for downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some more research here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949123/4252392.

The problem was that ViewBag's name is the same as the model's property.
So i changed the Viewbag's name.

**New Controller**

```
 public ActionResult EditContact(int? id)
 {
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var Contact = db.Contacts.ToList();
    ViewBag.ContactIDList = new SelectList(Contact.AsEnumerable(), "ID", 
                                           "name", "Contact");
    ClientModel client= db.ClientModel.Find(id);
    ClientEditContactModel model = new ClientEditContactModel();

    model.ID = client.ID;
    model.ContactID = client.ContactID 

    return View(model);
}
```

**New View**

```
@model Project.Models.ClientEditContactModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ContactIDList, 
                                "select a contact")
```

Comment: Note, it should be `ViewBag.ContactIDList = new SelectList(Contact, "ID", "name")` Remove the last parameter. And you do not need `AsEnumerable()` - its already `IEnumerable`! (I assume `PurchaseContact` should be `Contact` or else its `var PurchaseContact = db.Contacts;` - again no need to use `.ToList()`)

Answer (score 0):

If you set selected value in ContactID property from dropdown so you need to set dropdown in view like below:

```
@model Project.Models.ClientEditContactModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Contact,
                      "select a contact")
```

Comment: I just noticed I did it like that in the code but didn't put it right in the question. But it still doesn't work with the viewmodel.

Comment: Just confirm that after change the code is any value is selected in dropdown or not or just displayed “select a contact”?

Comment: I found the solution and fixed my question. I hope it is clear now. Made some typos. My apologies for that.