# dropdownlist not selecting the value ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I know this question has been asked already here in SO, but I can't distinguish my error from this post : [DropDownListFor Not Selecting Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278056/dropdownlistfor-not-selecting-value?rq=1)

I did not use ViewBag's name the same as the model's property coming from the link.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Companies = db.Companies.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

and this is my code in the view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Id", "ShortName"), "Select a Category")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentId)
    </div>
```

in my create form, the dropdown list generates without error, however after clicking create, an error states "value cannot be null" even though I have selected a value.

I even added the ViewBag again in the [POST]Create Action :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Company company)
    {
        ViewBag.Companies = db.Companies.ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Companies.AddObject(company);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(company);
    }
```

I don't know where the error resides, I am completely new to ASP.NET MVC.

Here is the error log:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean when you return the view after the post? (if so, you need to reassign `ViewBag.Companies` before returning the view)

Comment: When saving the newly created data from the form. What do you mean need to reassign? Sorry for noobish question.

Comment: You edit shows that you reassign the `ViewBag` property so that's OK (although you should move it to the line immediately before `return View(company);` - no point doing it if you redirect so its unnecessary extra overhead). Can you post the full details of the error.

Comment: That error is saying that the first parameter of the `SelectList()` constructor (`IEnumerable items`) is `null`, meaning that `ViewBag.Companies` is null when you return the view. Are you sure your code is exactly as you have posted?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the controller and in the view, and inspect ViewBag.Companies

Comment: Unrelated: If this is new code you should use MVC 5.2.X (preferrably 5.2.3)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I found the error : "Select a Category" <- this is causing the error. However, I want that to be the default value if none is selected.

Comment: @BreaktheLaw, That has nothing to do with it. If the value of `ParentId` does not match one of the option values (defined by the `Id` property of `Company` then the first ("Select a Category") option will be selected. The stack trace clearly shows that the value of `ViewBag.Companies` is `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I am sure. I posted the needed codes in detail for my issue to be fully understood. But why is the error not displaying anymore when I removed the Select a Category?

Comment: Changing `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Id", "ShortName"), "Select a Category")` to `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Companies, "Id", "ShortName"))` will make no difference unless you have some other problems with you code. All the 3rd parameter does is perpend `<option value>Please a category</option>` to the `<select>` tag.

Comment: Suddenly I reverted back the default option Select a Category in my view., and it still works, I look like an idiot here, wondering how did that work. I did not change any code in my controller