# DropDownListFor not setting selected value with different names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I feel like this is very simple and I have done my research here:

[Research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278056/dropdownlistfor-not-selecting-value)

But it is not working.

Controller:

```
ViewBag.OwnerValue = new SelectList(db.tableName, "ID", "AName", object.OwnerID);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AID, ViewBag.OwnerValue as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In my research the answer said to change the name of the ViewBag property so that it doesn't match the actual property name.. so that's what I did and the selected value is still not being set.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `model.AID` has selected id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the model property `AID` before passing the result to View in your controller action:

```
ViewBag.OwnerValue = new SelectList(db.tableName, "ID", "AName");

model.AID =  object.OwnerID;
return View(model);
```