# Creating Html.DropDownList with Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a dropdown list that contains values from my data model.  I cannot seem to get this to work inside of my view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Program Types", 
new SelectList(Model.Select(x => x.ProgramType.ProgramType).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x),
Model.Select(x => x.ProgramType.ProgramTypeId).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by cannot get it to work, do you get exception or does the dropdownlist does not appear at all

Comment: WOW, have you considered using view models? If you haven't then, well, have :-) When I see this code in a view I feel the need to drink beer.

Comment: You are using `new SelectList` incorrectly.  You are passing in more then one item to the `object` parameter of the constructor.  It is meant to have a SINGLE object passed to it and that object is what is considered the `selected` item in the drop down list.

Comment: Support beer drinking! :) And, yes, use view models. Make life so much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

[How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

It doesn't get any simpler than that and you can adjust this example to your case quite easily.

Hope this is of help to you & good luck!