# ViewBag null control in DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TransferAvailibilities.First().CancellationID, 
(ViewBag.CancellationSchema == null ? null : 
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CancellationSchema), new { @class = "field large" })
```

**And error**:

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CancellationID'.

I know that but i will bind data with ajax when i need. And my lambda not work or something for DropDownListFor...

Answer (score 0):

Create `SelectList` from your `ViewBag.CancellationSchema` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.intClient, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "ClientId", "ClientName"), string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong. Instead of explaining how and why, please take a look into this posting, will clarify things for you on how to use `@Html.DropDownListFor`:

[How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

Comment: My think that is not wrong syntax or something. I can see now a life cycle problem only. I solve my problem with another way. Render is firing before than lambda expressions...