# MVC DropDownListFor - NullReferenceException was unhanded by usercode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net, MVC. I am trying to populate my dropdownlist. I found following solution for that.
[How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor) I am trying BARAT's solution for that but facing error of NullReferenceException. Following is my code.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CreditCardType,
        new SelectList(
            new List<Object>{
            new { value = 0, text="VISA"},
            new { value = 1, text="Master"},
            new { value = 2, text="Debit"}},
            "value",
            "text",
            Model.CreditCardType)
            )%>
```

ErrorDetail: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can Anyone please help me? I might be making small mistake but not able to fix it.

Comment: post the details of your `NullReferenceException`

Comment: What should be the datatype of my Model.CreditCardType Object? May be there I made mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks LostDreamer for your comment. I made following changes in my code and it's working now. I don't know why Mode.CreditCardType was not working. In the reference, they have used the same thing but it is not working in my case. anyway following is solution.

```
  model.CreditCardType,
        new SelectList(
            new List{
            new { value = 0, text="VISA"},
            new { value = 1, text="Master"},
            new { value = 2, text="Debit"}},
            "value",
            "text", 
            "VISA")
            )%>
```