# MVC4 DropDownList issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm building an MVC4 app, and I cannot get Html.DropDownList to behave at all. All the actual page is showing is a submit button, and it doesn't actually render the drop down list.

This is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var items = new SelectList(
            new[] {
                new { Value="ships", Text="Ship" },
            },
            "Value", "Text"
        );

        ViewData["tableitems"] = items;

        return View();
    }
```

And this is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Encyclopedia", FormMethod.Get)) {
    @*<select id="table" name="table">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="ships">Ship</option>
    </select>*@

    Html.DropDownList("table", ViewData["tableitems"] as SelectList, "Ship" );

    <input type="submit" value="view" />
}
```

I've been searching online for hours trying various permutations, but I can't get it. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor

Comment: That was one of the pages I was looking at, but I still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an `@` in front of the `Html.DropDownList`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Encyclopedia", FormMethod.Get)) {
    @Html.DropDownList("table", ViewData["tableitems"] as SelectList, "Ship" );
    <input type="submit" value="view" />
}
```

Without the `@`, your code is just evaluating to an `MvcHtmlString` but it's not actually being rendered to the view, that's where the `@` comes in!