# Cant write proper postback method using DropDownListFor in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, dropdownlistfor

I've created model constains field like this

```
public Dictionary<int, string> Egg { get; set; }
```

and view to show combobox like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Egg.Keys,
                     new SelectList(
                         Model.Egg, 
                         "Key", 
                         "Value"))
```

but I can't write a httppost method at controler class because every time I face this error

> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.CollectionHelpers.ReplaceDictionaryImpl(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEnumerable`1 newContents) +131

I am reffering this article:
[How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor/10393006#10393006)

Answer (score 0):

In view side:

```
@model Models.MyEggs

...

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Egg.Keys,
                         new SelectList(
                             Model.Egg, 
                             "Key", 
                             "Value"))
```

In Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {                
            var model = new MyEggs();

            return View(model);
        }
```