# Adding a dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If MVC only allows you to have one ViewModel per View, how does one incorporate a dropdownlist (need to have a separate ViewModel for this) into an existing View which is already used by another ViewModel (ie an entity which has a column for this dropdownlist)?

Comment: Why in the world would you think a drop down list requires a separate view model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Question in addition, I guess, Got everything  you are looking for:

[How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

As a beginner, I did a very basic implementation of dropDownlist using the NorthWind Database only.

I had imported the Product & Suppliers table from Northwind database.

In the `ProductController.cs` file, which is the controller file for my `Product`  table, add method: `GetAllSuppliers` to get all SuppliersID which we will display in a dropdown.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetAllSuppliers()
        {
            NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
            return db.Suppliers.Select(e => e.SupplierID);
        }
```

Now, in the `Create` action method in `ProductController.cs`, pass all the values of `SupplierID` in `ViewData` as seen below:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
            {

                ViewData["Suppliers"] = new SelectList(GetAllSuppliers());
                return View(new Product());
            }
```

In your corresponding `Create.aspx View`, use this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SupplierID, ViewData["Suppliers"] as SelectList) %>
```

Below is a snapshot of the Result:

[image]

Let me know if you need any explanation.

Comment: Thank you! The basic implementation was what i was looking for.  Worked for me nicely!!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a property inside your main ViewModel which contains ViewModel for dropdownlist and use it with dropdown.

Assume you have controller.

```
public class HomeController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel
    {
      SomeProperty = "SomeValue",
      DropDownData = new DropDownDataViewModel() // Initialize it with appropriate data here.
    };

    return this.View(viewModel);
  }
}
```

And MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
  public DropDownDataViewModel DropDownData { get; set; }
}
```

So, inside your view you can call `@Model.DropDownData` to get access to this viewmmodel.

Comment: AlexK, got the idea, but could you provide a simple code snippet example?