# Get DropDownListFor to display name of each model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How do I get a DropDownListFor helper to properly display all of the items of a model that a collection has?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Request.Leave_ID, new SelectList(Model.Leaves))
```

I tried modifying this part of code in many different ways but I'm not too good with Linq so I either got something like System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies... etc returned or something else that is weird.

Basically my model has a colleciont of a Leave model which contains a Name property so I would like to make it possible so that the dropdown list will display the names of all of the Leaves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

Comment: Well I'm mostly interested in seeing if there is a Linq query which would make this happen

Comment: Linq query is for data. and you already have Leaves in your model. Why do you need Linq query here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dataValueField and textValueField parameters to the constructor of the SelectList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Request.Leave_ID, new SelectList(Model.Leaves, "Name", "Name")))
```

Comment: @Andrew: If this answer helped you resolving your issue, then you should mark it as answer.

Comment: @NitinJoshi I wanted to but it made me wait 2 minutes and then I forgot