# DropDownListFor within a ForEach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model, which has a `List<SelectListItem>` which holds a list of Third Parties.

In my view, I need to iterate through the list, and create a DropDownList for that data, based on an id I have, called 'SelectedEntityId'.

I do the formal ForEach:

> @foreach (var line in Model.Lines)
>   {

And then, I attempt to render my drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>line.SelectedEntityId, new SelectList(Model.ThirdParties, "Value", "Text"), "Select One", new{@class="form-control"})
```

However, even though I see (in debug mode) that the 'SelectedEntityId' has the value of 5 (in this case), and that Model.ThirdParties has that item value - the drop down doesn't display that item, but rather its at 'Select One'.

I think it's possible my syntax `x=>line.SelectedEntityId` is incorrect?

I am getting a warning on the word "line" therem saying `"Access to foreach variable in closure. May have different behaviour when compiled with different versions of compiler."`

Can I do that, in a `foreach`, and reference the value of the item in my `foreach` like that?

Comment: Maybe not related, but if `ThirdParties` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` why are you creating a new `SelectList` from it? Note also this wont post back correctly as all the dropdowns will have the same `name` attribute - for that you need a `for` loop so the controls are correctly indexed

Comment: Just use `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks! How should I do the 'For' version there? The answer to that will provide me with the way forward.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; Model.Lines.Count; i++) { @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Lines[i].SelectedEntityId, Model.ThirdParties, "Select One", new { @class="form-control" });`

Answer (score 0):

what is `line` here. As i am familiar it should be like `x=>x.SelectedEntityId` however rest code is fine and it should work well guessing you have **Value** and **Text** fields in your List. i've seen some examples too related to this have a look on below links if you still facing some issue.

[html-dropdownlistfor](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/how-to-simple-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc-net/)

[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)