# Best programming practice of using DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with MVC 5 for a few months read a lot of articles, forums and documentation but always wondering what is better in the view;

1) binding data using static method of model like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

2) binding the same data using ViewData[index] which is set in Controller that with previous example will look like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.MyColorId, ViewData[index])
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd go for the option that lets the compiler cry foul if you refactor the model.  `ViewData[index]` is more brittle in this case.

Comment: One thing ViewBag/ViewData have going for them though is that you don't have to reference System.Web.Mvc in your model class (for SelectListItem). You might like to keep your model classes separate as a bridge between DAL and repository, with no requirement to know anything about ASP.NET MVC.

You could always meet halfway by making 'AvailableColors' a Dictionary<long,string> instead and Select-ing to a List<SelectListItem> on the page itself, but that's not particularly attractive either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use option 1, mainly because you want to use **Strongly Type** as much as possible, and fix the error at compile time.

In contrast, **ViewData** and **ViewBag** are dynamic, and compile could not catch error until run-time.

Here is the sample code I used in many applications -

### Model

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public string SelectedColorId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableColors { get; set; }

    public SampleModel()
    {
        AvailableColors = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model DemoMvc.Models.SampleModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedColorId, Model.AvailableColors)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

}
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SampleModel
        {
            AvailableColors = GetColorListItems()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var colorId = model.SelectedColorId;
            return View("Success");
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        // ** IMPORTANT : Fill AvailableColors again; otherwise, DropDownList will be blank. **
        model.AvailableColors = GetColorListItems();
        return View(model);
    }

    private IList<SelectListItem> GetColorListItems()
    {
        // This could be from database.
        return new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Orange", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Red", Value = "2"}
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say, completely separate dropdown items from `ViewData`. Have your model contain a property for dropdown. Fill that in your controller and just bind it in the view like

#### ViewModel

```
class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropdowndata {get; set;}
}
```

#### Controller

```
public Actionresult MyAction(string id)
{
     IEnumerable<data> mydata = callDALmethodtogetit();
     Mymodel model = new MyModel 
                     {
                        dropdowndata = mydata.Select(c => new SelectListItem 
                                                       { 
                                                          Value = c.Id.ToString(), 
                                                          Text = c.Name 
                                                       });
                     }
 }
```

#### View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dropdowndata, Model.dropdowndata)
```

Comment: If in model 'A' I only need ID of model 'B'  why I sould keep collection of all models 'B'?

Comment: @DespeiL, I given a sample code to show what I am saying. intention is to  get the dropdown data as part of controller action and in view you should just bind it and nothing more than that.

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - the model needs a separate property (say `int SelectedItem`) to bind to.