# populate dropdownlistfor mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I having a problem understanding some of the datatypes and datasets with MVC and LINQ. I am trying to populate a dropdownlist.

I receive the following error *(noted below in the code)*

> "Unable to create a constant value of type 'vps_intranet.Models.Part'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

**PartsController.cs**

```
private List<Part> partsNotPartOfStructure(int partID)
{
    Part mainPart = db.Parts.Find(partID);
    //var alreadySelected = db.Parts.Select(p => p.PartStructures_comp).Distinct();
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();

    List<PartStructures> excludeList = db.PartStructures1
        .Where(p => p.mainPart_id == partID).ToList();

    parts = db.Parts.Where(c => c.PartStructures_comp
        .Except((List<PartStructures>) excludeList)).ToList();
    //The line above gives the error...
    //Unable to create a constant value of type 'vps_intranet.Models.Part'.
    //Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

    return parts;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Part part = await db.Parts.FindAsync(id);
    if (part == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewData["AvailableParts"] = partsNotPartOfStructure(id.Value);
    return View(part);
}
```

**Details.cshtml**

```
@model vps_intranet.Models.Part

@{ 
    var fullList = (IEnumerable< vps_intranet.Models.Part >) ViewData["AvailableParts"];
    var availableParts = fullList.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.partNo.ToString(), Value = p.id });
}

...

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartStructures_comp, availableParts));
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929483/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-ty) help?

Comment: You are trying to use  an `Exclude` between two different data types. You have the `Part` class and then the `List<PartStructure>`. Do it by parts. First, get the parts. Then, cast it to the list of part structures and then do the exclude

Comment: You might want to look at [DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818949/best-programming-practice-of-using-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/37819577#37819577)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a list of `PartStructures` class objects to the `Except` method. Except method uses the default equality comparer to compare the values.

If you are passing a custom class (*not a simple value type like `int`*) , You should implement  `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface methods such as `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

If you do not prefer to do that, You can get the Ids of your PartStructures collection and use that with the `Contains` method.

```
var excludeIdList = db.PartStructures1.Where(p => p.mainPart_id == partID)
                      .Select(g=>g.Id).ToList();

var parts = db.Parts
          .Where(c => !c.PartStructures_comp.Any(g=>excludeIdList.Contains(g.Id)))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand better what I was doing wrong. However, the result is the parts in the exclusion list and not the rest of the list. I tried using Except but I got an error. Obviously I have a bit to learn. How would you implement the Except clause in place of the contains?

Comment: As i explained in the answer, If you want to use Except, you need to implement  `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. What is wrong with the solution i posted ? It should give you all the parts which does not have PartStructures_comp with Ids same as ids in the exlucdeIdList variable.

Comment: I implemented your fix before you added the ""== false" and it returned the records included. After putting in the "==false", it returns no records.

Comment: Sorry ! The linq code was wrong. I fixed it now (the second line). Let me know if that does not work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an `Exclude` between two different data types. You have the `Part` class and then the `List<PartStructure>`. Do it by parts. First, get the parts. Then, cast it to the list of part structures and then do the exclude.

You have to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Taken from: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6694563/1188208) post.

```
public class Compare : IEqualityComparer<Part>
{
    public bool Equals(Part x, Part y)
    {
        return x.SomeProperty == y.SomeProperty;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Part part)
    {
        return part.SomeProperty.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This way you could do

```
var parts = db.Parts.Exclude(someList, new Compare());
```