# @Html.DropDownList - set particular text at top to display

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

@Html.DropDownList - set particular text at top to display

### code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Plant",ViewData["PlantList"] as SelectList, new {style="height: 29px;"})
```

The dropdownlist has five items from viewdata. They are one, two, three, four, five.

I am having another as `viewdata["displaytext"]`.
Here any 1 value from the options will be present. say for example now `three` is present in *this* `viewdata`. How to set this `three` to be `display text`

EDIT
Adding controller method:

```
public ActionResult PlantList()
{
     ...
     ...
     ViewData["PlantList"] = pList;
     ViewData["displaytext"] = "three";
     return view();
}
```

Comment: Set the value of property `Plant` to `"three"` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, and the option with `"three"` will be selected.

Comment: Can you give as a short answer for my understanding.

Comment: I just did in the comment :). You have not shown your model (do you even have a property named `Plant`), or the controller method, and a detailed answer is not possible until you do so.

Comment: I am passing `ViewData["PlantList"]` as a five options values. Then I am passing `viewdata["displaytext"]` as a single value. Then I am having the line of code as `return view();`

Comment: Edit your question with all the relevant code.

Comment: I had updated my question

Comment: @StackOverflow You might want to look at [Best programming practice of using DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37819577/296861).

Comment: Your not returning a model to the view (and you still have not even shown the model). It needs a property `string Plant` and you set the value in the controller - `var model = new MyModel{ Plant = "three" }; return View(model);` and the correct option will be displayed (that's how model binding works). And your model should also contain `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PlantList` rather that using `ViewData`. And you should always use the strongly typed `***For()` methods - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Plant, Model.PlantList)`

Comment: already `cshtml` page uses another model for different functionality. How to add another model in that page.

Comment: Then create a view model ([What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)) which is the very first thing you should be doing anyway

Answer (score 0):

Create a model;

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Return model to view.

```
public ActionResult Index
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.Number = "three";
    return View(model);
}
```

and in you view;

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Number,ViewData["PlantList"] as SelectList,"", new {style="height: 29px;"})
```

And the "three" option will be selected.

This is a simple example. Create the related code with your model.

Comment: I had used  `@Html.DropDownList` and not `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Comment: So you are not returning a model to view?

Comment: Change the view code with this then

@Html.DropDownList(ViewData["displayText"],ViewData["PlantList"] as SelectList, new {style="height: 29px;"})