# asp.net mvc set DropDown Selected Value - not in model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a class for that is used to create a reusable dropdown on create/edit views:

```
  public class TimeDropDowns
    {
        public static int SelectedHour{ get; set; }
        public static List<SelectListItem> hours = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="9", Value="09"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="10", Value="10"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="11", Value="11"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="12", Value="12"}
                };

    }
```

I am able to display the dropdown 2 ways:

1) in a view `@Html.DropDownList("hour", TimeDropDowns.hours, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

2) setting using viewbag in controller `ViewBag.hours = TimeDropDowns.hours;` 
and then referencing in view  `@Html.DropDownList("hours", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

But I haven't been able to set the selected value using either approach, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the feedback of the 2 responders I have decided that creating a strongly typed model was the best approach. Since my model was generated from the db I needed to create a partial class so that I would not lose changes if db model refreshed. I created the partial class which is a type of my model class

```
namespace TouchScreenEvents
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TouchScreenEventMetadata))]
    public partial class TouchScreenEvent
    {
        public string selectedHour { get; set; }
        public  List<SelectListItem> hours = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() {Text="9a", Value="09"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="10a", Value="10"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="11a", Value="11"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="12p", Value="12"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="1p", Value="13"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="2p", Value="14"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="3p", Value="15"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="4p", Value="16"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="5p", Value="17"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="6p", Value="18"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="7p", Value="19"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="8p", Value="20"}
            };

        public string selectedMinute { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> minutes = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() {Text="00", Value="00"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text="30", Value="30"}
            };
    }
}
```

To set the selected index in the controller I have this code (unnecessary parts removed)

```
//get edit touchscreen event
TouchScreenEvent touchScreenEvent = await db.TouchScreenEvents.FindAsync(id);
var d = touchScreenEvent.date;
touchScreenEvent.selectedMinute= d.ToString("mm");
touchScreenEvent.selectedHour = d.ToString("HH");
```

And the view code, with previously selected value set. This will also work without the selected index being set - in the create view for instance

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedHour, Model.hours, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedMinute, Model.minutes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When posted back to the controller I can access the values like this

```
touchScreenEvent.selectedHour, touchScreenEvent.selectedMinute
```

Comment: It looks great. My only suggestion will be to use ***PascalCasing*** for ***Public Properties***. You can read more at [.Net Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Answer (score 1):

The class `SelectListItem` has a property called `Selected`. It's type is bool. When this property for an item is true, then it's value is selected.

That being said you need something like this:

```
public class TimeDropDowns
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> GetHoursDropDown(int? selectedHour = null)
    {
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for(var hour=9; hour<=12; hour++)
        {
            var hourStr = hour.ToString();
            var item = new SelectListItem 
            {
                Text = hourStr, 
                Value = hour < 9 ? "0"+hourStr : hourStr, 
                Selected = selectedHour.HasValue && selectedHour == 9
            }
            items.Add(item);
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Then you could use this as below:

```
ViewBag.hours = TimeDropDowns.GetHoursDropDown(11);
```

If you want the selected hour to be the 11th or like:

```
ViewBag.hours = TimeDropDowns.GetHoursDropDown();
```

if you want none of them to be selected.

The place of 11, when you post your form, would be taken by the value you post, `hour`. Apparently this value should be parsed first and the you will pass it to the `GetHoursDropDown` method.

I strongly encourage you, as already Win have mentioned correctly in his post, to avoid the use of ViewBag and create a strongly type view model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set DropDownList as ***SelectedHour*** instead of ***hours***, so that *ModelBinder* can bind the selected value to *SelectedHour* when form is posted back to server.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedHour", ...)
```

*I personally like to use Strongly Typed Model. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819577/296861).*

Comment: I already have a model, should I add a 2nd just for this? I am using several dropdowns to create a datetime value in the model

Comment: I am using it for the date, but I also need hours and minutes, which is what I am creating these dropdowns for

Comment: For date time, you can use Kendo UI's [DateTime Picker](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index). You just add one line of jQuery code `$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker();`, and you are done. Beside, kendo DateTime Picker is part of [Open Source and Free HTML5 Framework](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core).