# Get value from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have simple site

controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Dodaj()
    {

        EduSiatkiEntities daneProgramu = new EduSiatkiEntities();

        SelectList profileHasel = new SelectList(daneProgramu.SYS_PROFILE_HASEL.Select(e => new{ Value = e.idProfiluHasla, Text = e.nazwaProfilu,}), "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.profileHasel = profileHasel;
        ViewBag.CzyZapisanoDane = "nie";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Dodaj(Models.UzytkowniDodajkViewModel uzytkownikForm)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(uzytkownikForm.idProfilHasla.Where(x => x.Selected=true).FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString());
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            /**/
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.CzyZapisanoDane = "nie";
        }

        return View(uzytkownikForm);
    }
```

view.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.idProfilHasla, (SelectList)@ViewBag.profileHasel, "Wybierz opcje...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

model.cs

```
[Display(Name = "Profil hasła użytkownika")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Wybierz profil hasła użytkownika")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> idProfilHasla { get; set; }
```

When i debug the program I alway get NULL value from DropDownList (from code below)

```
Debug.WriteLine(uzytkownikForm.idProfilHasla.Where(x => x.Selected=true).FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code for this - `Models.UzytkowniDodajkViewModel`

Comment: Ok. First, "edit" your question and paste the class in the question and not as an answer. Secondly, you seem to be binding a drop down list selected _item_ to an IEnumerable which makes little sense. Change your IEnumerable to string and try with that.

Comment: A `<select>` binds to and posts back a single value (not a collection of complex objects). Your `idProfilHasla` needs to be `int` (or `string`) and the value of `idProfilHasla` in the POST method will be the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.idProfilHasla, (SelectList)@ViewBag.profileHasel, 
     "Wybierz opcje...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For above DropDownList , ***idProfilHasla*** should be ***string*** type, because DropDownList selected value is a string.

```
[Display(Name = "Profil hasła użytkownika")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Wybierz profil hasła użytkownika")]
public string idProfilHasla { get; set; }
```

*If you want to place SelectList inside model instead of ViewBag, you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819577/296861) answer.*

Comment: When I do this (code above) - I get error:   **System.InvalidOperationException** :key idProfilHasla1, is type System.String, but must be  IEnumerable<SelectListItem>