# The given key was not present in the dictionary. in Razorview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have error `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` in Razor view

Please check below code

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    @foreach (var country in ViewBag.countryList)
    {
        <option @((country.CountryCode == "GB") ? "selected" : "") value="@country.CountryCode">@country.CountryName</option>
    }
</select>
```

My `Country` Model Class

```
public class Country
{
    public long CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

For `ViewBar.countryList` i add like this

```
List<Country> countryList = Common.getCountry();
ViewBag.countryList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(countryList);
```

Please check in below image i already got data in variable but i also get error as above.

[image]

Comment: `public class Country
    {
        public long CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: i add `ViewBag.countryList` add using list Please check updated post.

Comment: Then how to solve this error

Comment: Where in your viewmodel do you set ViewBag.countryList ?

Comment: Ideally, you want to use strongly type ViewModel with DropDownList Html Helper. You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819577/296861).

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: @PareshMaghodiya Replace `var` with `Country` - I'm betting that, because you are using the `ViewBag`, the type information is not carrying over and the `var` is typing it to something it's not. (Like a `char`, as named in the error.)

Comment: I also used `Country` in place of var but also get same error

Comment: @PareshMaghodiya Have you verified that `country` contains what you expect it to contain in the loop body?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Airport> airportCodeList = Common.getAirport();
ViewBag.airportCodeList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(airportCodeList);
```

Should be

```
List<Airport> airportCodeList = Common.getAirport();
ViewBag.countryList= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(airportCodeList);
```

Don't use the ViewBag for this, use a strongly typed model, also use DropDownList Html Helper as in the other answer

Also, why do you serialize it? Just assign the objects

```
ViewBag.countryList= airportCodeList;
```

Comment: I give wrong list code please check new update in question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use like this

```
  List<Airport> airportCodeList = Common.getAirport();
    ViewBag.airportCodeList = airportCodeList;

    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.airportCodeList, "ID", "Name"))
```