# Creating a DropDownList in MVC that still populates the model backing it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a small model called GoalTypes which would contain stuff like "Running, Cycling, Weight.." etc

```
public class GoalType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a model called Goals
  public class Goals
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartDate  { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public  DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

public string Type { get; set; }
public double Level { get; set; }
```

}
The type field would be populated by the Type field from GoalTypes.
In my goals controller I have done:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.listOfGoals = new SelectList(db.GoalTypes, "Id", "Type");
    return View();
}
```

and in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("listOfGoals", "Select a Goal")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

this populates the dropdown but if i submit it, the type field is left blank

Comment: Because you creating  form control named `listOfGoals` but your model does not have a property with that name (its `Type`). Your editing data so always use a view model. Refer the code in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical example (your using the worst possible overload to generate a `<select>` element which does not give 2-way model binding or client side validation)

Comment: You might want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819577/296861).

Comment: When you submit a dropdownlist you are submitting selected value but not the complex type.  Can you inspect the formcollection upon submitting?

Comment: @gardarvalur im happy submitting the selected value, if Im only getting to grips with this stuff so maybe later down the line I will edit it to submit complex types.

Comment: @CeriWestcott well, it sounds as if you need javascript to help you out with that. Maybe I am misunderstand but it sounds as if you would need to hook onto the onselect event of the dropdownlist to update the form with new selected type, perhaps with partialview injected into the form.  I am not sure...

Comment: @gardarvalur, You definitely do NOT need javascript. The view just needs to be be generated correctly - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listOfGoals, "Select a Goal")` (except that the property should be `int Type`, not `string`)

Comment: @CeriWestcott What are the parameters of the post action?

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass you @ViewBag for the @Html.DropDownList, as follow:

```
@Html.DropDownList("listOfGoals", ViewBag.listOfGoals)
```

or create a helper:

```
public class MyHelpers{
   public static SelectList DropDownListGoalTypes(int? selected) {
        var list = db.GoalType.ToList();
        return new SelectList(list, "Id", "Type", selected);
   } 
 }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, MyHelpers.DropDownListGoalTypes(Model.Id))
```

Comment: That's not necessary if `listOfGoals` is available in `ViewBag` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: In that case, the View doesn't seem be a typed view.

Comment: It's not strongly typed even with the second parameter. I think you misunderstood what I meant. If you populate `ViewBag.listOfGoals` in the controller, and you have `@Html.DropDownList("listOfGoals")` in the view, it will work as it is. No need to add the `(SelectList)ViewBag.listOfGoals` explicitly as you have suggested in the first part of the answer.

Comment: I get it, there is no need for casting.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted, once it has given an answer, and the code above works.

Answer (score -1):

`@Html.DropDownList("listOfGoals", "Select a Goal")` generates a select element like this:

```
<select name="listOfGoals" id="listOfGoals"></select>
```

But you're trying to bind the dropdown to `Type` property in your model upon submission,

So, you need to change it to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listOfGoals, "Select a Goal")
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listOfGoals, "Select a Goal")
```

Now, the `select` is created with `name` attribute as "Type" and the `DefaultModelBinder` can bind it to the property in the `POST` action.

Also, as Stephen suggested, you need to change the `Type` to an `int`. Because the `value` of the selected `option` is submitted, not the text.

```
public int Type { get; set; }
```