# How can I bind CountryNames in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using mvc4. How can I Bind CuntryName and its values in DropdownList
**Country**?

```
public class Country
{
    public int Cnt_Id { get; set; }
    public string Cnt_Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my private class

```
public class HybridEmployee
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> GetCount { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetCountry()
{
    var x = ObjRepo.GetCountry();
    hybrid.GetCount = x;
    return View(hybrid);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model  Mvc_Application.Models.HybridEmployee
@using Mvc_Application.Models
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEmp", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.GetCount.FirstOrDefault().Cnt_Id),new SelectList(Model.GetCount,"","");
}
```

Comment: `new SelectList(Model.GetCount,"Cnt_Id","Cnt_Name")` but you also have your parenthesis wrong, and you cannot use `x=>x.GetCount.FirstOrDefault().Cnt_Id` - not only does it not make sense, it wont bind to anything anyway. You need a property to bind to, say `public int SelectedCountry { get; set; }`

Comment: @stephen could u plz reffer any demo

Comment: Suggest you refer the code in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) to understand how to create and bind to a dropdownlist

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor to find out how `DropDownListFor` model binding works - the first argument must not use LINQ with lambda expression, but a property from viewmodel that holding selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have two approaches as shown below:

1. Using a `ViewBag` containing the data for dropdown list.

**Model file:**

```
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }
}
```

**In .cs file:**

```
ViewBag.Countries = countryService.All().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
```

**In .cshtml file:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, ViewBag.Countries as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

2. Using a Model's property containing the data for dropdown list.

**Model file:**

```
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

**In .cs file:**

```
model.Countries = countryService.All().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
```

**In .cshtml file:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, Model.Countries, "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank u soo much @Reyan

Comment: Recommending using `ViewBag` rather than a view model which OP already has is dreadful advice

Comment: Except that `int CountryID` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries` should be in OP's `HybridEmployee` class (not sure what your `State` class is - it has nothing to do with OP's question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke State class is an example. I thought you would be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This expression totally doesn't makes sense:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.GetCount.FirstOrDefault().Cnt_Id),new SelectList(Model.GetCount,"","");
```

The first argument of [`DropDownListFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573.aspx) helper (`Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression`) doesn't use LINQ expression, it is model binding expression - you must use a property to hold selected value instead. The drop down list binding should be used like this:

**Model**

```
public class Country
{
    public int Cnt_Id { get; set; }
    public string Cnt_Name { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCountry { get; set; } // additional property to get selected value
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.GetCount, "Cnt_Id", "Cnt_Value"), null)
```