# How to write Html.DropDownListFor() for an enumerable in a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First I've read through the answers given here which are very useful: [How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

They helped for when you just have one model and nothing to iterate over except for the instances created from that model, but what do you do when you have an enumerable inside of a model, that you want to create a drop down for?

What I'm trying to do is create a dropdown list from a list of students and display their First Name and Last Name as the fields, with their own object or ID as the value fields.

StudentsCourses Viewmodel

```
public class StudentsCourses
{
    public ICollection<Student> Students;
    public ICollection<Course> Courses;
}
```

Students model

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enrollment Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set;}
}
```

I'm feeding the viewmodel into the view via this in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        StudentsCourses sc = new StudentsCourses()
        {
            Courses = _context.Courses.ToList(),
            Students = _context.Students.Include(e => e.Enrollments).ThenInclude(c => c.Course).ToList()
        };

        return View(sc);
    }
```

This is what I have so far on the view:

```
<h3>Register a Course</h3>
<form asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Select Student</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.Student, new SelectList(Model.Students, "FirstMidName", "LastName"))
    </div>
</form>
```

But it does not work, there is a red squiggly under "n.student" from "n => n.Student)"

Comment: The red squiggly comes because your model doesn't have a property named "Student".  It has one called "Students".  Aside from that, I'm not sure what you expect or want to happen here.

Comment: I pretty much just want a dropdown that shows all the students

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects. A `<select>` binds to a posts back a simple value (the value of the selected option). You need a property (say `int SelectedStudent`) to bind to. Refer the code in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical example.

Comment: View models are specific to views. So if your view needs to render only a dropdown, you should have properties needed to render that ( a list of `SelectListItem` for the option list and an `int` type for the selected value). Check the duplicate i flagged with, specifically the **Getting data from your database table using entity framework** section. The only thing you have to change is , replacing `context.Employees` with `context.Students`