# How to correctly use DropDownListFor in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using MVC Core with repository Pattern to handle operations. I am trying to generate a `select` element using `DropDownListFor` but recieve the following error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Products.CategoryId' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'

The main model(Products) with be using data as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from other models. Here is the code in the (Products) View:

```
@HTML.DropDownListFor(c => c.Products.CategoryId, Models.CategoryList, "--Select Category--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

https://github.com/AliZ801/ShoppingCenter

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057931/6527049

Comment: I am using dynamic list data instead of static

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: I have something similar. In repository, I created a method special for drop down list and assigned the value to it and then simply just called that method in controller. Even though i tried this 1 but same error!

Comment: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoryListForDropDown() { return _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Text = i.CatName, Value = i.Id.ToString() }); } //This method is called in constructor for Category List