# @HTML.EditorFor: Creating DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am new to ASP .Net Web Application MVC (.Net Framework Visual Basic) and having issue creating a **hardcoded** drop down list.

Have searched multiple sources but still unable to solve my problem.

From what I know, Create/Edit.vbhtml is the form to modify field from textbox to drop down list. And I have not changed anything on my Controller.vb that has been generated automatically when creating this project.

Below is the original code of mine:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Product, New With { .htmlAttributes = New With { .class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: As the documentation states, the `EditorFor` method renders an `input` element. The `DropDownListFor` method renders a `select` element. Presumably you want the latter.

Comment: @John I still couldn't solve it by changing EditorFor to DropDownListFor. How to set all the value for <select></select>?

Comment: Does [How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor) help?

Comment: You should edit the question and show us the new code.

Comment: Why did you specify Hard Coded drop down list but I saw in your code you have a Model which is supposed to be not hard coded. Do you want a sample code in Visual Basic to implement a DropDownList? Kindly be specific in the question :)