# MVC 2: How to use Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm not exactly sure on my lambda's yet but why isn't the following working? 4/mvc2

Works:

```
// SpotlightsController.cs
public class SpotlightFormViewModel
{

    // props
    public Spotlight Spotlight { get; private set; }
    public SelectList Featured { get; private set; }
    public IDictionary<string, int> feature = new Dictionary<string, int>(){
        {"True", 1},
        {"False", 0},
    };

    // constr
    public SpotlightFormViewModel(Spotlight spotlight)
    {
        Spotlight = spotlight;
        Featured = new SelectList(feature.Keys, spotlight.Featured);
    }
}

// Edit.aspx
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="Featured">Featured:</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("Featured", Model.Featured)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessage("Featured") %>
</div>
```

Doesn't work:

```
// Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments
// Edit.aspx
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Featured) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Featured)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Featured) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462.aspx) takes (at least) two arguments.  The first argument is the property that will hold the selected value on postback (and contains the current selected value) and the second is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` containing the key/value pairs for the options.  Rename your Feature property to FeatureMenu or something and create a property name Featured of the type corresponding to the option's value.  Then add the FeatureMenu to the DropDownListFor's arguments.

```
 public SelectList FeatureMenu { get; private set; }
 public string Featured { get; private set; }
```

...

```
 <%: Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Featured, Model.FeatureMenu ) %>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it looks like now I just have to work around the DDL bug described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916462/dropdownlistfor-in-editortemplate-not-selecting-value

Comment: Hmm.  I haven't seen that particular issue, but then again I typically use a custom method to return views that ensures that the menus are populated based on which view I'm returning.