# MVC3 Razor SelectList.MakeSelection issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, selectlist

I'm working on a MVC3 web application. I want a list of rotation shown in view. But during build I get error:

> Error 2971    'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition
>   for 'MakeSelection' and no extension method 'MakeSelection' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

My code in view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobFiles[i].JobPages[j].UserRotation, (ViewData["rotation"] as SelectList).MakeSelection(Model.JobFiles[i].JobPages[j].UserRotation))
</div>
```

Please help. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is telling you that the `MakeSelection` function does not belong to the `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList` object. I did find this extension method -

```
public static SelectList MakeSelection(this SelectList list, object selection)
{
    return new SelectList(list.Items, list.DataValueField, list.DataTextField, selection);
}
```

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916462/dropdownlistfor-in-editortemplate-not-selecting-value), are you missing the extension method from your code?