# MVC4 binding drop down list in a list (bug)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, binding, html.dropdownlistfor

*I have the below code in a view. (index.cshtml)*

**Binding Problem**

- The first drop down selects the correct value, based on the 'ChildItem' editor template.
- The second example using an inline drop down list *does not work* I don't want to create an editor template just to display drop down values.
- The odd thing is that TextBoxFor will show the correct value. This seems to be an issue just with the drop down list.

How do I fix the binding so that the second drop down works? I debugged it. It would appear that ViewData.Eval is not picking up the correct value from `_.Children[i].ChooseId`.

**Update (bug)**
*This is a confirmed bug (low priority, how?) in the MVC framework http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8311*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count(); i++)
    {
       <p>A: @Html.EditorFor(_ => _.Children[i], "ChildItem")</p>
       <p>B: @Html.DropDownListFor(_ => _.Children[i].ChooseId, TestModel.PeopleSelect)</p>
    }
    <button type="submit">GO</button>
}
```

I have tried using `DropDownListFor(_ => Model.Children[i].ChooseId)`, same result.
using `TextBoxFor(_ => _.Children[i].ChooseId)` shows the correct value, **wierd?**

For reference here is `ChildItem.cshtml`

```
@using dropdown.Controllers
@using dropdown.Models
@model dropdown.Models.TestPerson
@Html.DropDownListFor(_ => _.ChooseId, TestModel.PeopleSelect)
```

It looks like this:

[image: A works, B does not.]

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373336/asp-net-mvc4-models-child-collection-drop-down-list-not-binding-properly/52750667#52750667

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have subsequently found this: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8311
It's a confirmed bug.

The only workaround i have found is this.

### Mark Selected Item

`@Html.DropDownListFor(_ => _.Children[i].ChooseId, Mark(TestModel.PeopleSelect, Model.Children[i].ChooseId))`

### Mark Function / Extension Method

```
@functions {
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Mark(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object Id)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            if (string.CompareOrdinal(item.Value, Convert.ToString(Id)) == 0)
                item.Selected = true;
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm facing the same issue, because I'm setting the HtmlFieldPrefix to something different.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the items into a partial view and load that for your child objects, OR...

You could opt to do a `foreach` loop on the child collection, and use it like this:

```
foreach (var itm in Model.Children)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => itm.ChooseId,
          new SelectList( (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TestModel.PeopleSelect, "Value", "Text", itm.ChooseId),
          htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
    )
}
```

This assumes that `TestModel.PeopleSelect` has been created as a `SelectListItem[]` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.  Code to do that properly is in my answer on a related question:  [ASP.NET MVC4 Model's Child Collection Drop Down List not binding properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373336/asp-net-mvc4-models-child-collection-drop-down-list-not-binding-properly/52750667#52750667)

Doing a `for` loop on the child collection gave me the error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ICollection<Children>'

So I wouldn't recommend that.