# C# MVC2 DropDownListFor bug after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to fix a bug on an MVC2 page with a dropdown. My problem is that after submitting the form, I change a value in my model server side for the dropdown but when the view is rendered again the new value is not selected.

I have defined my dropdown in the view as follows.

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyValueId, MyHelperClass.GetMyDropdown())%>
```

I have a helper class to generate my dropdown list, the function looks like this.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetMyDropdown()
{
    List<SelectListItem> options= new List<SelectListItem>();
    options.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "None", Value = string.Empty });
    options.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MyValue", Value = "1" });
    //and more options added in the same way
}
```

On my view page I also have a submit button to allow the user to recalculate the value of my dropdown. When the user clicks the button the form is submitted and the controller action looks like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyViewName(MyModel model, string submitButton)
{
    //check for my submit button value
    if(submitButton == "Recalculate")
    {
        int newValue = 0;
        //some logic to set the new value
        model.MyValueId = newValue;
    }
    return View(model);
 }
```

When I debug my code, I can see the new value is created and set properly in the model. I can see in my dropdown generate method the list is created properly and an option with my new value exists. In the view I can debug and see what the model still has the correct value, but for some reason the dropdown is always the first option - Text = "None" Value = "".

I have tried to simplify my code as much as possible to avoid confusion, but I will explain in more detail if needed. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I might be missing something here - but are you setting the Selected property in the appropriate SelectListItem in GetMyDropdown?

Comment: Yes I am, but I omitted it from my post as I thought that using Html.DropdownListFor automatically set the selected item using the model binding anyway?

Comment: Have you looked at this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916462/dropdownlistfor-in-editortemplate-not-selecting-value

Comment: None of the answers seem to work. In my helper class I am assigning the Selected property of the right item but still the dropdown doesn't update. I might also mention that it doesn't just reset back to my empty option, it just stays at whatever it was when the user submits the form. Also my model value is a nullable int, which might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `ModelState.Clear()` before `return View(model)`.
Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

It's not a bug, it's by design...