# .Net Core 3 Razor Page Admin/Product/Upsert.cshtml IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, crud, razor-pages

I am trying to develop a project with razor page. When I say create product from the product page, I encounter the IEnumerable  error. Since I no longer know what to do, I wanted to share my problem here. Thank you in advance for your answers. I also wrote the Turkish equivalents of some words to understand:

urun->product

urunAdi->product name

urunAciklama->product Description

kategori->category

resimYolu->imagePath

**before the error:**
[image]

**after the error:**
[image]

**Admin\Product\Upsert.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model Propeboru.Pages.Admin.Product.UpsertModel

<form method="post" asp-action="Upsert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row px-2 mx-2  border">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            @if (Model.ProductObj.Product.urunID != 0)
            {
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductObj.Product.urunID" />
            }


           

            <div class="col-12 px-3" style="border-bottom:1px solid #325d88">
                <h2 class="text-primary">@(Model.ProductObj.Product.urunID != 0 ? "Düzenle" : "Oluştur") Ürünler</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-8 pt-3">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label asp-for="ProductObj.Product.urunAdi"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="ProductObj.Product.urunAdi" />
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ProductObj.Product.urunAdi"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label asp-for="ProductObj.Product.urunAciklama"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="ProductObj.Product.urunAciklama" id="txtDesc" style="height:200px;"></textarea>
                     </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label asp-for="ProductObj.Product.kategoriID"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductObj.Product.kategoriID,
                                                 Model.ProductObj.CategoryList ,
                                                 "- Lütfen ürünün kategorisini seçiniz !-",
                                                 new { @class = "form-control" })
                        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ProductObj.Product.kategoriID"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label asp-for="ProductObj.Product.resimYolu"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <input type="file" class ="form-control" name="files" id="uploadBox" />
                       
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-9 offset-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                @if (Model.ProductObj.Product.urunID != 0)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Düzenle</button>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" onclick="return ValidateInput()" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Oluştur</button>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Listeye Dön</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: "lists",
        menubar: "file edit format"
    });

    function ValidateInput() {
        if (document.getElementById("uploadBox").value == "") {
            swal("Error", "Lütfen ürün resmini seçiniz !", "error")
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
   
}
```

**Admin\Product\Upsert.cshtml.cs:**

```
 public class UpsertModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public UpsertModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

        }

        [BindProperty]
        public ProductVM ProductObj { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
        {
            ProductObj = new ProductVM
            {
                CategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetCategoryListForDropDown(),
                Product = new Model.Product()

            };

            if(id !=null)
            {
                ProductObj.Product = _unitOfWork.Product.GetFirstOrDefault(u => u.urunID == id);
                if(ProductObj.Product == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            if(ProductObj.Product.urunID == 0)
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, @"images\product");
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                using(var fileStream=new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads,fileName+extension),FileMode.Create))
                {
                    files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                ProductObj.Product.resimYolu = @"\images\product\" + fileName + extension;

                _unitOfWork.Product.Add(ProductObj.Product);
            }
            else
            {
                var objFromDb = _unitOfWork.Product.Get(ProductObj.Product.urunID);
                if(files.Count>0)
                {
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, @"images\product");
                    var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);

                    var imagePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, objFromDb.resimYolu.TrimStart('\\'));

                    if(System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
                    }


                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                    ProductObj.Product.resimYolu = @"\images\product\" + fileName + extension;

                    //_unitOfWork.Product.Add(ProductObj.Product);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProductObj.Product.resimYolu = objFromDb.resimYolu;
                }

                _unitOfWork.Product.Update(ProductObj.Product);
            }
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
```

**ProductController.cs:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public ProductController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Product.GetAll() });
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var objFromDb = _unitOfWork.Product.GetFirstOrDefault(u => u.urunID == id);
                if (objFromDb == null)
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "silinme hatası" });
                }
                var resimYolu = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, objFromDb.resimYolu.TrimStart('\\'));
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(resimYolu))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(resimYolu);
                }

                _unitOfWork.Product.Remove(objFromDb);
                _unitOfWork.Save();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "silinme hatası" });
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Başarıyla Silindi" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: in ProductObj object model add catagoryid as a property 

so can bind like m => m.ProductObj.kategoriID

Comment: The problem should be casued by the `CategoryList of ProductObj` is null. Does the error appear when you click the create button or when the page just loads? Please make sure that the CategoryList of your ProductObj has received data of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Forgive formatting, on mobile)

DropDownListFor requires a select list collection

Your first parameter is the property you want to assign to, then you need to have the second parameter as a SelectList

```cs
DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductObj.Product.KategoriID, new SelectList(Model.Products));
```

You'll need to replace `Products` with your own collection of Product, that's a property in your model.

Refer to this for more info: [DropDownListFor in EditorTemplate not selecting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916462/dropdownlistfor-in-editortemplate-not-selecting-value)

Ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_SelectExtensions_DropDownListFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Web_Mvc_SelectListItem__System_Object_